# Почему при повороте экрана пропадает прогресс в активити?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Друзья прошу помощи)
При повороте экрана пропадает прогресс активити, так же когда перехожу в другое активити и обратно - тоже пропадает прогресс, что нужно исправить или сделать? спасибо

```
    package com.example.testappv1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView upgrade_img;
    private static ImageView men_level_img;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ConstraintLayout baseFonClicker;
    private TextView money_text;
    private TextView level_text;
    private static int countMoney = 0;
    private static int countProgress = 0;
    private static int countLevel = 1;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        upgrade_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.upgrade_img);
        men_level_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.men_level_img);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10000);
        money_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_text);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
        level_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_text);
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        baseFonClicker = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.basefonclicker);

        baseFonClicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (countLevel == 1) { LevelOne(); }
                if (countLevel == 2) { LevelTwo(); }
                if (countLevel == 3) { LevelThree(); }
                if (countLevel == 4) { LevelFour(); }
                if (countLevel == 5) { LevelFive(); }
                if (countLevel == 6) { LevelSix(); }
                if (countLevel == 7) { LevelSeven(); }
                if (countLevel == 8) { LevelEight(); }
                if (countLevel == 9) { LevelNine(); }
                if (countLevel == 10) { LevelTen(); }

            }
        });

        upgrade_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpgradeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("level", level_text.getText());
                intent.putExtra("money", money_text.getText());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void postProgress(int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        if (progressBar.getProgress() >= progressBar.getMax()) {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            countProgress = 0;
            countLevel++;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelOne() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        countMoney++;
        countProgress = countProgress + 1000;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelTwo() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb2l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 2;
        countProgress = countProgress + 900;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelThree() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb3l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 3;
        countProgress = countProgress + 800;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelFour() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb4l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 4;
        countProgress = countProgress + 700;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelFive() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb5l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 5;
        countProgress = countProgress + 600;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelSix() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb6l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 6;
        countProgress = countProgress + 500;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelSeven() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb7l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 7;
        countProgress = countProgress + 400;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelEight() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb8l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 8;
        countProgress = countProgress + 300;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelNine() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb9l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 9;
        countProgress = countProgress + 200;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void LevelTen() {
        level_text.setText("Уровень: " + countLevel);
        men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb10l);
        countMoney = countMoney + 10;
        countProgress = countProgress + 100;
        postProgress(countProgress);
        money_text.setText("Монеты: " + countMoney);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("countLevel", countLevel);
        outState.putInt("countProgress", countProgress);
        outState.putInt("countMoney", countMoney);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        countLevel =  savedInstanceState.getInt("countLevel");
        countProgress =  savedInstanceState.getInt("countProgress");
        countMoney =  savedInstanceState.getInt("countMoney");
        levelPicture(countLevel);



    }

    void levelPicture(int countLevel) {
        if (countLevel == 1) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb1l);
        } else if (countLevel == 2) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb2l);
        } else if (countLevel == 3) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb3l);
        } else if (countLevel == 4) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb4l);
        } else if (countLevel == 5) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb5l);
        } else if (countLevel == 6) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb6l);
        } else if (countLevel == 7) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb7l);
        } else if (countLevel == 8) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb8l);
        } else if (countLevel == 9) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb9l);
        } else if (countLevel == 10) {
            men_level_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bb10l);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: сделал countMoney, countProgres, countLevel  статическими, теперь когда перехожу в другое активити и обратно прогресс сохраняется, но когда переворачиваю экран прогресс так же обнуляется

Answer (score 2):

Всякий раз при смене конфигурации (в том числе и повороте экрана) активити пересоздается заново. И все методы жизненного цикла вызываются заново. Вам необходимо обрабатывать эти кейсы. Здесь есть несколько кейсов:

- метод `savedInstanceState()` - в него вы можете положить простые данные вроде строки или числа и при пересоздании активити эти данные можно получить из бандла в `onCreate()`.
- хранить данные в сущностях которые переживают жизненый цикл активити и при каждом пересоздании получать данные из них. К примеру если у вас есть список заказов, передавать его через `savedInstanceState()` очень плохая практика. У вас может быть база данных в которую активити будет ходить всякий раз при пересоздании.

Более подробно в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle?hl=ru).

Comment: Есть движение)теперь при повороте экрана все данные сохраняются, но если я перехожу в другое активити и возвращаюсь обратно, то TextView money_text и TextView level_text отображаются корректно (с прогрессом), а  для ProgressBar progressBar и private ImageView men_level_img нужно один раз нажать на экран чтобы прогресс появился, надеюсь поняли что я хочу сказать)спасибо, код отредактировал

Comment: Надо смотреть и дебажить. Так я вам не скажу. Но очевидно, что проблема в том что при открытии новой активити у вас меняется состояние предыдущей Activity. Вам надо смотреть что и где вызывается по метода ЖЦ